# GET url 401 & Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at getData

Tags: javascript

```
const URL = "url";
const key = "abc-abc-abc";

  const getData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(URL, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "X-Auth-Token": key,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
  });

  console.log(await res.json());
};
getData();
```

I am getting the errors
-> GET url 401
-> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input const res = await fetch(URL, {   at getData()

Comment: The 401 would mean that your auth token is invalid, as long as you don't also get a cors policy error. But I tried with an unprotected api endpoint and this code should work, so it must be the auth method or the key.

Comment: why you putting await in console.log(await res.json()); your res will always awaited untill fetch call is completed.

Comment: @KiwiRupela Please send me the correct code and I should use get request only

Comment: @TD3V I reverified the token it's 100% correct and ya i should perform GET request only

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Did you check whether the API works as expected?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes check the answer section

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well the code was perfectly fine.
The problem was with my chrome browser

```
In the command prompt
**First type**
cd "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application"  
**Next**
chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:/ChromeDevSession"
```

Comment: That sounds like a horrible idea. How should anybody else use your website?

Comment: This is not my personal project